# nvd3 does not calculate maximum y value correctly

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a problem to calculate the maximum y-value from my data

I use

```
var maxY = d3.max(d3.merge(data.map(function(d){return d.values})), function(d) {return d.rank});
```

And then

```
.yDomain([maxY,1])
```

to set the domain.

But as you can see in my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Marei/v4ca3pz6/), it does not work - while the max y in my data is "12", the graph displays a maxY of "90".

It's the first time im using nvd3 so maybe someone here can help me out and have a look to find out what I am doing wrong?
Thank you so much!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to adilapapaya I figured it out for our test fiddle by adding the missing "+"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return +d.rank;` in your `maxY` computation. Otherwise, `d3.max` will compute max values assuming a `String` input.

Comment: Wow, that easy. I was blind! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome~! If this answered your question, please go ahead and accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the rank as a `Number`. Try wrapping `d.rank`. Ex: `parseInt(return d.rank)`